# single slurm array vs multiple sbatch calls

Tags: slurm

I can run `N` embarrassingly parallel jobs by using a `slurm` array like:

```
#SBATCH --array=1-N
```

Alternately I think I can achieve the same from a scheduling perspective (i.e. scheduled independently and as soon as resources become available) by manually launching 8 job. For example with a simply bash script with a loop.

Since the latter is far more flexible, I don't see the utility I using the --array option built into slurm.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays offer a simple way to create parametrised jobs without writing the Bash loop. It

- (obviously) creates the jobs and assign them a parameter ;
- takes care of output file name parametrisation ;
- makes the submission of a dependent job that should run after all those jobs are completer much easier
- makes the output of `squeue` less cluttered

Furthermore, the jobs in an array can be managed as a whole, the `squeue`, `scancel`, etc. command can work on the whole array as opposed to writing another loop to cancel them for instance. This is even more interesting in the case you have multiple arrays running at the same time ; you do not need to manage the tracking of each individual job by yourself.

Finally, especially for large arrays, it makes the scheduler easier and can increase the job throughput.

If you need flexibility, then job arrays are not the solution, but maybe a [workflow manager](https://events.prace-ri.eu/event/1321/contributions/) could help you.

Comment: If there are plenty of jobs in the array, and each job requires huge amount of resources (nodes, gpu, etc), will the scheduler keep the job in pending state until resources available for all jobs in the array? Or jobs in the array could start separately (as in the case of multiple sbatch calls)?

Comment: Each job will be started independently of the others based on the resources available and the cluster policies. So they could start all at the same time.